# how to map data array to object array?

Tags: laravel

I have data as below:

```
langauges: [
   {
     "langauge_id": 2, "grade_id": 3
   },
   {
     "langauge_id": 5, "grade_id": 7
   }
];
```

I want to transform data to be like this as below:

```
[2 => ['grade_id' => 3], 5 => ['grade_id' => 7]]
```

Please help me out! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of Collection's [`mapWithKeys`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys) method.

You should have a collection like this:

```php
$collection = collect([
    ["language_id" => 2, "grade_id" => 3],
    ["language_id" => 5, "grade_id" => 7]
]);
```

Then, you can manipulate this data, mapping it to whatever you want:

```php
$mappedCollection = $collection->mapWithKeys(function ($language) {
    return [$language["language_id"] => ["grade_id" => $language["grade_id"]]];
});
```

If you want to have an array, remember to do `$mappedCollection->toArray();`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data:

```
$langauges= collect([
            [
                "langauge_id" => 2, "grade_id" => 3
            ],
            [
                "langauge_id" => 5, "grade_id" => 7
            ]
        ]);
```

You can use:

```
  $groupByLang=$langauges->keyBy('langauge_id')->map(function ($item) {
        return collect($item)->only(['grade_id'])->toArray();
    });
```

Comment: If he has a lot of items, this is not performant as you are iterating everything 2 times and doing a lot of things like `only` or `keyBy` when you could do it in one iteration and no more calls to anything else.